# How can I Add ACL rules at run time for all model?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to create acl rules at run-time for all models.
I have form that contain ACL information Like:

```
id, 
model name,
property,
accesstype,
principalId, (here I am assign roldId from role table).
PrincipalType.
```

After submit the form, information will be stored in ACL table (DB: mysql). My question is how to get the data in mixin or boot scritpt or any  and when will get acl data from acl table and how to assign to all model at runtime.

I am tried in mixin and boot script but I cant get clear idea.

In mixin file, how to get acl data and how to assing to all models..

I am realy confused because I dnt no when will push acl data in runtime for all model(like boot, mixin, operation hook).

Please give any ideas.

I want to like, In mixin or boot script or any.

Get all data from acl  and assign to all models.

```
In mixin.// I don't know how to get acl data from database in mixin files. 
ACL.find(function(err, data)
{
    var acl = data;
});

// doing some iteration..

 Model.settings.acls.push(data);
```

Comment: I haven't done this before, but the idea is not to add the ACL to the model, but rather to [create an ACL](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#acl) _for a model_ and then [add it to the registry](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#addacl). Again, I haven't done this before, but good luck!

Comment: Jakererlla Thanks for your response. if you try and get result please share me.

Comment: Can you share any example or tutorial for add registry,I am just 1 week before started  strongloop. and can you share any real time strongloop application for training purpose .

Comment: Hi I have another question. How to apply acl rules for models from acl table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ACL(base Class) collect and concatenate  both static JSON acl rule and ACL Table data at run-time so It will work automatically.

> get Static ACL from Model.JSON ex: user.json

```
ACL.getStaticACLs = function getStaticACLs(model, property) {
var modelClass = loopback.findModel(model);
var staticACLs = [];
if (modelClass && modelClass.settings.acls) {
  modelClass.settings.acls.forEach(function(acl) {
    var prop = acl.property;
    // We support static ACL property with array of string values.
    if (Array.isArray(prop) && prop.indexOf(property) >= 0)
      prop = property;
    if (!prop || prop === ACL.ALL || property === prop) {
      staticACLs.push(new ACL({
        model: model,
        property: prop || ACL.ALL,
        principalType: acl.principalType,
        principalId: acl.principalId, // TODO: Should it be a name?
        accessType: acl.accessType || ACL.ALL,
        permission: acl.permission
      }));
    }
  });
}
var prop = modelClass && (
  // regular property
  modelClass.definition.properties[property] ||
  // relation/scope
  (modelClass._scopeMeta && modelClass._scopeMeta[property]) ||
  // static method
  modelClass[property] ||
  // prototype method
  modelClass.prototype[property]);
if (prop && prop.acls) {
  prop.acls.forEach(function(acl) {
    staticACLs.push(new ACL({
      model: modelClass.modelName,
      property: property,
      principalType: acl.principalType,
      principalId: acl.principalId,
      accessType: acl.accessType,
      permission: acl.permission
    }));
  });
}
return staticACLs;
```

};

> get ACL from ACL table(database)

```
var self = this;
var roleModel = registry.getModelByType(Role);
this.find({where: {model: model.modelName, property: propertyQuery,
  accessType: accessTypeQuery}}, function(err, acls) {
  if (err) {
    if (callback) callback(err);
    return;
  }
  var inRoleTasks = [];

  acls = acls.concat(staticACLs);
```